# Add metadata to fields in proto3 for Java

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, proto3

Proto3 has been simplified such that the `required` and `optional` fields are no longer supported (See [Why required and optional is removed in Protocol Buffers 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801257/why-required-and-optional-is-removed-in-protocol-buffers-3)). Is there still a way to label a certain field as `required`?
I've looked into `FieldOptions`, and tried something like this:

```
message MyMeta {
  bool isRequired = 1;
}

extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
   MyMeta meta = 1234;
}

message Person {
  string name = 1 [ (meta) = { isRequired: true }];
  string address = 2  [ (meta) = { isRequired: true }];
  string remarks = 3;
}
```

After compiling it into Java code, and as I was checking the compiled Java code I don't see any link between the fields and its metadata I specified in proto. Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of tinkering and using @Eric Anderson's idea on using proto reflection, here is a way to retrieve `MyMeta` from the `Person.name` field:

```
    Descriptor rootDesc = PersonProto.getDescriptor();
    FieldDescriptor name = rootDesc.findFieldByName("name");
    FieldDescriptor ext = rootDesc.getFile().getExtensions().get(0);
    MyMeta meta = (MyMeta) name.getOptions().getField(ext);
    boolean isReq = meta.getIsRequired();
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that functionality was removed; use documentation instead. If you are trying to use FieldOptions for your own extensions, then you can make your own protoc plugin to generate supplemental code (like a verify utility) or use proto reflection at runtime (via `FooMessage.getDescriptor()` and `Descriptors.FieldDescriptor.getOptions()` in Java).

Comment: Thanks! Though I felt we need to provide a more specific answer on how to retrieve the field metadata in Java.